# Getting too many requests error own worpress plugin?

Tags: solana-program, transactions, api, solscan, webapp

Hello everyone recently i was developing a wordpress plugin to check SLP transactions from and to wallet by providing both wallet addresses and use it on my own website. Recently it was working fine. but, all of sudden it says too many requests. Actually i was testing it by sending approximately 100- 200 requests totally. This is how it works sending get requests to api > get latest 10 transactions > loop each transactions by tx >  confirm the transaction by from and to wallets, by symbol and by amount. So why i am getting too many requests ?

Comment: Can you specify exactly which RPC requests you were making? Keep in mind that the public endpoints are unfortunately very strict about their rate limits because of abuse in the past.

Comment: I am using purple RPC what are the alternative RPC?